# How to put an if condition under columns in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Can we add a if Condition inside the column while describing the columns of the grid? Whats wrong in this code
    I want to display one button in the grid under a column ,if length of the text exceeds more than 40char.
I am trying to put an if condition if the content/data is less than 40 char then display the content else display a button , On click of button open a pop-up to display the complete content inside that pop-up?
How we can put the command conditionally to display the button?

Here is my code

```
columns: [{
    field: "id",
    title: "ID",
    width: "100px"
}, // fields in  the grid
{
    field: "name",
    title: "Name",
    width: "100px"
}, {
    field: "remarks",
    title: "Remarks",
    width: "160px", // under this column button will be displayed in each
    var length = 40;
    if (data.remarks.length > length) { //here this condition seems to be wrong, is there any other way to display the button for this condition
        command: {
            name: "remarks",
            text: "Remarks",
            click: function (e) {
                var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
                var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                var win = $('#remarksWindow');
                win.html(data.remarks);
                if (!win.data('kendoWindow')) {
                    win.kendoWindow({
                        width: '600px',
                        height: '200px',
                        title: 'Remarks',
                        actions: ['Close']
                    });
                }
                win.parent().css({
                    top: e.pageY - 50,
                    left: e.clientX - 640,
                    width: '600px',
                    height: '200px'
                });
                win.data('kendoWindow').open(); // open the pop-up which contains the data
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
},
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a syntax error in JavaScript. Note that you can't put statements or declarations between the properties of an object:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    if (true) {
        b: 2;
    }
}
```

Or

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    var b = 1;
}
```

The examples above doesn't works. So in your `column` property you have to use a [`template`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template) property:

```
{
    field: "remarks",
    title: "Remarks",
    width: "160px", 
    template: "" // <- here goes your logic
}
```

So a simple `template` can be set as a *string* containing html with JavaScript logic, e.g.:

```
# if (remarks.length > 40) { # <input type='button' class='btn-remarks' /> # } #
```

Yes, you will have to set the button html by yourself. [There is no way to add a condition to a `command` button](http://www.telerik.com/forums/conditionally-visible-custom-command)(and that is a shame, actually).

<sup>You can check how `template` works [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview).</sup>

Then your column item should be:

```
{
    field: "remarks",
    title: "Remarks",
    width: "160px", 
    template: "# if (remarks.length > 40) { # <input type='button' class='remarks' /> # } #"
}
```

Then you have to set the event for all your buttons(probably in the [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) event):

```
$("#yourGrid").on("click", ".btn-remarks", function() 
{
    // all your click logic here
});
```

Give it a try and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this dojo is what you are looking for: http://dojo.telerik.com/ETora

(I have used one of Telerik's grid demos and modified to show you the principles)

The functionality you are looking for can be achieved by two means:

1) Apply a client Template to the column

2) Add a databound event that then hooks up the buttons

```
 columns:[ {
              field: "CompanyName",
              title: "Company Name", 
              template: "#= displayTextorButton(data.CompanyName) #"
         }]


 function displayTextorButton(data){
                var retString = ''; 
                console.log(data); 
                if(data !== null && data !== undefined)
                {
                  if(data.length > 20)
                  {
                    retString =  ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"' +
                    'data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto right" data-container="body" ' +
                'data-content="' + kendo.htmlEncode(data) + '"' +
                'data-title="Running Log Information"  data-trigger="click" data-role-me="content-popover" > <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span> View</button>'; 
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                    retString = '<span>' + data + '</span>';
                  }
                }else 
                {
                  retString = '<span> - </span>'; 
                }

                return retString; 
              }
```

so the first bit I have done is added a template to the Company Name column that checks if the name is more than 20 characters if it is then it will display a button if it isn't then it will display the text as normal.

```
 function(e){
             $('button[data-role-me="content-popover"]').popover({ trigger: "focus", html: true });
                  }
```

I then hook up a databound event to the grid to then attach the event features to the "pop up" in my sample

Also note I have hooked in the bootstrap features just to make things a little easier for the demo. So this is using their popover feature. You could modify this code to work with your window.

Any issues let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.., It worked. But I am having one issue.., This code I have put in one directive and same is being called from two different screens. On One screen its working fine but on the other screen pop-over is not getting displayed. Not sure why? The other screen is kind of a model pop-up inside that we have section where grid is being launched .., there pop-over is not coming but button is getting displayed. If we launch from some modal pop-up then it wont work? or something else need to do?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you can provide a code example I will be more than happy to help try to fix the issue. It's a bit difficult to test with no code.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the kendo grid code

    { field: "marks", title: "marks",width: "160px",
                            template: function(dataItem) {
                                var marks = dataItem.marks;
                                var retString = ''; 
                                if(marks !== null && marks !== undefined)
                                {
                                  if(marks.length > 40)
                                  {
                                   marks1 = marks.substring(0, 40)+'...';
                                    retString1 ='<span>'+ marks1 +'</span>';
                                    retString =  retString1 + ' <button id="marksButton" type="button"' +
                                    'data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto right" data-container="body" ' +
                                    'data-content="' + kendo.htmlEncode(addlRemarks) + '"' +
                                    'data-title="marks" data-trigger="click" data-role-me="content-popover" > marks</button>';
                                  }
                                  else 
                                  {
                                    retString = '<span>' + marks + '</span>';
                                  }
                                }else 
                                {
                                  retString = '<span> - </span>'; 
                                }
                                return retString; 
                            }
```

And its being called from a HTMl

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="accOpen[$index]">
                                    <!-- Marks TABLE -->
                                    <div marks-table="" 
                                        accordion-flag="accOpen[$index]"
                                        name="name"
                                        id="id"
                                        >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: I have added your code into an updated dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/ETora/3 what is addlRemarks as it doesn't seem listed in the code sample and how does the second piece of code hook in? I am guessing you are using Angular (which I know very little about so will help out where I can)

Comment: Ya I am using AngularJs and this is how Its working for me also.., just want to ask if the table is launched in a modal-pop-up then its not behaving as expected..,pop-over is not coming

Comment: so do you have the grid inside a modal then?

Comment: I have updated the dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/ETora/4 showing the pop over working in a modal. Just check you are setting the container for the popover to the window rather than body as the popover will appear behind the grid and not in the grid.